# how do you extract from the json output using python

Tags: python

I have a json output from http request like this:

```
print(resp)
```

```
{'totalCount': 1, 'pageSize': 50, 'entities': [{'entityId': 'HOST-12345', 'displayName': 'beff'}]}
{'totalCount': 1, 'pageSize': 50, 'entities': [{'entityId': 'HOST-7898', 'displayName': 'dude101'}]}
{'totalCount': 1, 'pageSize': 50, 'entities': [{'entityId': 'HOST-56890', 'displayName': 'prop'}]}
```

I need to grab the entityId from this list:

```
HOST-12345
HOST-7898
HOST-56890
```

I have this:

```
print(resp['entities']['entityId'])
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: use `resp['entities'][0]['entityId']`

Comment: `resp['entities']` is a list with a single element... You need to first take that single element by indexing the list with `[0]` and then you get the dict to access with `['entityId']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current response is not in JSON format, in fact it is a string ! if this is what it is, you need to first split it with `"\n"` to get every line as a list item. Then you need to convert `'` to `"` (JSON doesn't support single quotation).

Now it is in JSON format and you can decode it with `json.loads()` to get the dictionary object and get information from it:

```py
import json

txt = """{'totalCount': 1, 'pageSize': 50, 'entities': [{'entityId': 'HOST-12345', 'displayName': 'beff'}]}
{'totalCount': 1, 'pageSize': 50, 'entities': [{'entityId': 'HOST-7898', 'displayName': 'dude101'}]}
{'totalCount': 1, 'pageSize': 50, 'entities': [{'entityId': 'HOST-56890', 'displayName': 'prop'}]}"""

for line in txt.split('\n'):
    correct_json_format = line.replace("'", '"')
    d = json.loads(correct_json_format)
    print(d['entities'][0]['entityId'])
```

output:

```
HOST-12345
HOST-7898
HOST-56890
```

Answer (score 0):

indices are always number, so to access line number 1 you have to write `resp[0]`, now using dots (.) you can access the inside fields.

```
print(resp[0]['entities'][0]['entityId'])
```